# Difference Between Minus and subquery

Tags: sql, netezza

i want to know what is the difference between Minus and subquery in the below example. I got 2 different results for both. Basically i am trying to find records that exist in the first but not the 2nd table.

Query 1:

```
select count(*) from (
(select OrderID
from DB.Orders)
MINUS
(SELECT OrderID 
  FROM DB.Shipments)) as abc;
```

Query2:

```
select count(*) from (
select OrderID
from DB.Orders as a1
where a1.OrderID Not in
(SELECT OrderID 
  FROM DB.Shipments)) as sub;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two possibilities:

In Query 1, `MINUS` is [implicitly `MINUS DISTINCT`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_combine_tbls_union_intersect_except.html).  Try `MINUS ALL`.

In Query 2, `NOT IN` does not behave well with `NULL` values.  Is `OrderID` allowed to be `NULL` in `DB.Shipments`?  Try `SELECT OrderID FROM DB.Shipments WHERE OrderID IS NOT NULL` in your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you troubleshoot:

```
select count(*), count(OrderID), count(distinct OrderID) from DB.Orders
```

Are all three numbers the same?